# Pass Touches from ScrollView to CollectionView below

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, touch-event

I have following view hierarchy:

UIView - root

-UICollectionView

-UIScrollView

BOTH are subviews of root view not of each other.

I want scrollview to only scroll vertically and collectionview to only scroll horizontally.

The problem I am having is getting the collection view to receive touches as it is underneath the scrollview.

Read other SO questions but was not able to find solution. Have tried overriding touches event methods in subclass of scroll view, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

An easiest fix would be to,

1) add `UICollectionView` to the `UIScrollView`,

2) Pin `UICollectionView`'s left, right, top, bottom to `UIScrollView`, and

3) Pin `UIScrollView`'s left, right, top, bottom to it's parent `UIView', if it has got one!

This way, they will both automatically know who needs to respond to which scroll events depending upon their contents.

Comment: The issue I have with this is that when the user scrolls up on scrollview the collection view will also scroll up, and when the collectionview is behind a view within scrollview it still does not receive touches. Desire is to have collection view always stay in one place, and when ever user scrolls in horizontal direction the collection view should move. Any ides?

Comment: This lead me the solution. I added collectionView as subview to scrollView and then override the layoutSubviews of scrollview to keep the collection view in place. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put an extra `UIScrollView` (1) above your existing `UIScrollView` (2) and `UICollectionView` (3), and set its delegate to an object that has references to (2) and (3) (e.g. your parent view or view controller). Implement the following method in that delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    _scrollView2.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, scrollView1.contentOffset.y);
    _collectionView3.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView1.contentOffset.x, 0.0);
}
```

(Don't forget to set `_scrollView1.contentSize` correctly.)

Comment: Interesting solution, will give this a try.

Comment: Basically have same issue with this approach because now _scrollView2 does not receive touch events for elements (like UIButtons) within it's subviews. All these touches are staying with scrollView1. Need way to pass events to view underneath(not subview) top view.

Comment: Wait, you want the user to be able to interact with items in your scroll view *and* in your collection view? I had assumed that you wanted both of them to be the same size as the parent view (i.e. cover each other completely). Is that not the case?